# Cherrypy: What is the difference between auth_basic and basic_auth

Tags: basic-authentication, cherrypy

Reviewing the tests of cherrypy I can see that test_auth_basic.py has the following conf:

```
'tools.auth_basic.on': True,
'tools.auth_basic.realm': 'wonderland',
'tools.auth_basic.checkpassword': checkpasshash
```

but the file test_httpauth.py shows:

```
'tools.basic_auth.on': True,
'tools.basic_auth.realm': 'localhost',
'tools.basic_auth.users': fetch_password,
'tools.basic_auth.encrypt': sha_password_encrypter}}
```

what is the difference between those tools? Do both implement Basic Auth? If so, why two different tools, is one deprecated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally bumped into this [link](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/wiki/WhatsNewIn32) that answers my question. basic_auth has been deprecated in favor of auth_basic.